# How to render a component for particular element in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array, for which a component (`<span>Delete</span>` in my case) needs to be shown only if the array length is greater than 2 and also, not show in first two array elements but show in other elements.

Example:
array = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
Show  `<span>Delete</span>` in "Three" and "Four" as the array is greater than length 2.
In the above case, even if the array is greater than length 2 don't show in first two elements ( "One" and "Two" ).

Code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = useState(["element"]);

  return (
    <>
      {element.map((e) => (
        <div>
          <span>{e}</span>
          {element.length > 2 &&  <span style={{color:"red"}}>{" "}Delete</span>}
          </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => setElement((element) => [...element, "element"])}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

The above code shows "Delete" text in all the elements

[image]

instead should show only for elements after the 2nd index.

[image]

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-16-9-forked-2w3lg5?file=/index.js:98-478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index of the element you're iterating over (the second argument in the `.map` callback) to check if the index is 2 or more - if so, you can show the delete, otherwise don't show it.

```
const App = () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState(["element"]);

  return (
    <>
      {elements.map((e, i) => (
        <div>
          <span>{e}</span>
          {elements.length > 2 && i >= 2 && <span style={{color:"red"}}>{" "}Delete</span>}
        </div>
      ))}
```

(Because the state is an array, making its name plural makes a lot more sense than a singular `element`, which sounds like an array *item*)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
{element.length > 2 && element.map((ele,index) => {
    if(index > 1){
        return <p>{ele}</p>
    }
    else{
        return <></>
    }
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check if the index of the current item is greater than `1`.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = React.useState(["element"]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {element.map((e, i) => (
        <div>
          <span>{e}</span>
          {i > 1 && element.length > 2 && <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Delete</span>}
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => setElement((element) => [...element, "element"])}>
        Add
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the current index of the current element (`e`), so include that in the parameter list of `map()`.

Secondly, the condition to check if the index (`idx`) is greater than or equal to (`>=`) 2.

```
const App = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = useState(["element"]);

  return (
    <>
      {element.map((e, idx) => (
        <div>
          <span>{e}</span>        
          {element.length && idx >= 2 && <span style={{color:"red"}}>{" "}Delete</span>}
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => setElement((element) => [...element, "element"])}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};
```